# Git deleting a remote branch that's not in remotes/origin

Tags: git, github

I had a remote branch called new_auth. I wanted a new remote branch to track that remote branch, so I did the following:

```
git-remote add -t new_auth -m new_auth pivot git@github.com:myco/my_project.git/my_project
```

Now when I do a git branch -a, I see:

```
* master
  new_auth
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/new_auth
  remotes/pivot/HEAD -> pivot/new_auth
```

I'd like to delete this remotes/pivot/HEAD -> pivot/new_auth. I've tried:

```
git push pivot :new_auth
git branch -rd pivot/new_auth
git remote rm pivot
git remote rm pivot/new_auth
```

No luck. Any ideas?

Comment: `git branch --notrack pivot/HEAD`?? ([man git-branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html))

Answer (score 2):

Your `remotes/pivot/HEAD` was created because you gave the `-m` option to  `git remote add` (the command will not automatically create the symref if you leave out `-m new_auth`).

A similar symref is created when you clone a repository. If a remote repository has a `HEAD` ref/symref, your clone of it will end up with `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` pointing to one of the remote-tracking branches corresponding to the remote branch pointed to by `HEAD` in the remote repository.

These symrefs let you refer to the “default branch” of a remote by just using the remote’s name (e.g. `pivot` “expands”<sup>1</sup> to `refs/remotes/pivot/HEAD`, which points to `refs/remotes/pivot/new_auth`).

You can delete the symref with this command:

```
git remote set-head pivot -d
```

<sup>1</sup> See the `<refname>` entry of Specifying Revisions in [*gitrevisions(7)*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

---

Overall, I am not really clear about what you were trying to accomplish with the `git remote add` command. If `pivot` and `origin` actually point to the same remote repository (same “Git URL”), then there should be no need for an additional remote. If you just want `origin/new_auth` to be the “upstream” branch for your local `new_auth` branch, then you can arrange that with

```
git branch --set-upstream new_auth origin/new_auth
```

(this can also be done with `git push -u` if you already have something ready to push). Once the upstream branch has been configured, you can use a bare `git pull` to automatically pull from `origin/new_auth` when you have `new_auth` checked out (you might also want to `git config push.default upstream` so that `git push` will only push to the upstream branch instead of pushing all branch names that exist in both your local and the remote repositories).

Comment: Thanks Chris! That worked. Just for clarification, there's no -- in front of the set-head part of git remote set-head pivot -d. I was trying to setup a remote ref to use for diff'ing remote branches. I knew once set it up it wasn't the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git push remotes/pivot/HEAD :new_auth
```

or

```
git push remotes/pivot :new_auth
```